# Binding Password of PasswordBox to another control

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, passwordbox

I'm working on an application internally in a company and they require some sort of user authentication. The code I have works perfectly for the authentication but there are some visual bugs.

*I know my code keeps the `Password` in memory and isn't they way it should be done but since this is internally for a company there is no benefit for hacking this. I like to hear if somebody has a better solution. It might be impossible since the `PasswordBox` is used inside in a `UserControl` inside a `UserControl`. This has to send the data all the way up and I have no idea how to do this secure.*

Now, back on topic. I created a `WatermarkTextBox` a while ago with the code shown below. The code below works like it should.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Watermark, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},
                  FallbackValue='This prompt dissappears as you type...'}"
           Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtUserEntry, Path=Text.IsEmpty,
                        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
<TextBox Name="txtUserEntry"
         Text="{Binding Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

Now I use a similar code for my `PasswordWatermarkBox`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Watermark, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, 
                  FallbackValue='This prompt dissappears as you type...'}"
           Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtUserEntry, Path=Password.IsEmpty,
                        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
<PasswordBox Name="txtUserEntry"
             local:PasswordHelper.Attach="True"
             local:PasswordHelper.Password="{Binding Path=Text,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},
                        Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Here I can use the `Text` DP to get the plain text password from the attached property `local:PasswordHelper.Password`. The problem here is that the `Watermark` does not update. Checking `Text.IsEmpty` in the first example works, but here it doesn't. Also `Password.IsEmpty` does not work and `local:PasswordHelper.Password.IsEmpty` does not work either.

Comment: We don't see the code of your PasswordHelper. [An example of an implementation is here](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html) if this is the root to your problem. Also your Anchestor binding there is a bit suspicious; RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}

Comment: My `PasswordHelper` comes from here: http://wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html